# Plotly: How to set zeroline opacity?

Tags: python, r, graph, plotly, axes

Is there a way to change the opacity of the zeroline in plotly? I am trying to layer the zeroline for my y-axis over my plot so it does not appear behind, but also have opacity/alpha of 50%. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [rgba color](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_colors.asp#:~:text=RGBA%20Colors,and%201.0%20(fully%20opaque).) together with `fig.update_xaxes()` and /or `fig.update_yaxes()`to get any color with any opacity you would like:

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(y=[1, -1], x=[-1,1])

fig.update_xaxes(zeroline=True, zerolinewidth=6, zerolinecolor='rgba(0,255,0,0.5)')
fig.update_yaxes(zeroline=True, zerolinewidth=6, zerolinecolor='rgba(0,0,255,0.5)')

fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank for this. Another solution which I tried before I saw the answer is to set a y=0 line and then do addtrace in R.